# Elastic net: How to improve unstable cross validation of lambda

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, glmnet, elastic-net

I want to tune lambda of an elastic net. It is possible to optimize lambda based on a cross validation with the `glmnet` package. However, I recognized that the estimated lambda varies a lot, if I run the cross validation several times. See code below, for a reproducible illustration of this situation:

```
library("glmnet")

set.seed(1234)

# Some example data
N <- 1000
y <- rnorm(N, 5, 10)
x1 <- y + rnorm(N, 2, 10)
x2 <- y + rnorm(N, - 5, 20)
x3 <- y + rnorm(N, 10, 200)
x4 <- rnorm(N, 20, 50)
x5 <- rnorm(N, - 7, 200)
x6 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x1) / (exp(x1) + 1))
x7 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x2) / (exp(x2) + 1))
x8 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x3) / (exp(x3) + 1))
x9 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x4) / (exp(x4) + 1))
x10 <- rbinom(N, 1, exp(x5) / (exp(x5) + 1))

data <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)

# Estimate lambda.1se several times
est_lambda.1se <- numeric()

for(i in 1:1000) {
  # Tuning in glmnet
  mod_cv_test <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(data[ , colnames(data) %in% "y" == FALSE]), 
                       y = y, alpha = 0.5, family = "gaussian")
  # Store lambda.1se
  est_lambda.1se[i] <- mod_cv_test$lambda.1se
}

# Distribution of the estimated lambdas
hist(est_lambda.1se, breaks = 50) # Could the median be taken?
```

[image]

In my example, lambda ranges approximately between 1 and 2.3. I am wondering if there is room for improvements. My idea is to take the `median` of all runs as *best lambda*. However, I am afraid that this procedure results in any problems which I can not see right now.

**Question: How could the tuning of lambda be improved?**

Comment: Use leave one out cross validation

Comment: Im not sure i understand the comment above. It would seem to me that while leave one out would give a definitive lambda, it only sweeps the issue under the rug by providing a point estimate of lambda with no variance estimate. The variability of lambda is true variance, the op has done themselves a good service by quantifying it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! It seems to me that k-fold is the standard procedure here, which would be another reason for me to stick with it in addition to the points of Matthew Drury. What do you think about my suggestion to use the median of several runs? I can not see any disadvantages of that, but I am relatively new to cross validation, so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're really asking here is about how sensitive the results are to your choice of $\lambda$, so I suggest you investigate exactly that. When I'm tuning an elastic net, if computation time isn't an issue I like to make a heatmap of the CV loss as a function of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ (or $\lambda$ and $\alpha$, depending on your software's parameterization). This exactly tells me the stability of my solution and I can see how much better my optimized point is than a 'random' point. You can also 'zoom in' until the noise of cross validation overpowers the actual increase in model performance (this is like doing a heuristic simplex search). Statements like 'this $\lambda$ is large' aren't really meaningful -- it's all data dependent, so for your data the difference between $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=2$ might be completely negligible, while for other data sets that's a massive difference.

Here's an example of the kind of heatmap that I'm talking about, taken from [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf) (which I suggest you read) by our very own @DikranMarsupial:

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ Chaconne! I just had a look at your suggested paper and it helped a lot to get a better insight! Would you just check the stability of the estimated lambda with your proposed method or would you also try to adjust lambda? What do you think about my suggestion to do several cross validation runs and then take the median of all `lambda.1se`?

Comment: @JoachimSchork if you repeat the CV with a particular $\lambda$ multiple times and average the CV losses you're just getting a lower variance estimate of performance for that particular $\lambda$. If you're really concerned about noise in your assessments of $\lambda$ this can help with that. But when you make a heatmap like the above you don't need to repeat the CV for any particular $\lambda$ because you'll have nearby $\lambda$'s and the loss should be continuously varying at large scales. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that actually helped a lot @ Chaconne. Thank you very much!

Comment: >  "When I'm tuning an elastic net, if computation time isn't an issue I like to make a heatmap of the CV loss as a function of 1 and 2."


Just to be clear @jld is it nice convex shapes of the contours that tell you about stability? Or do you *also* plot the contour and the loss function ponts(like the one with yellow +) to see how they cluster in the valleys?.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

You can try the `train` function in the `caret` package, it can easily tuning the `alpha` and `lambda` parameters at the same time.

What you caught at this unstable situation, it telling you maybe the falling in the local minimum.

I have run this example multiple times, this is what i got:

The local minimum of lambda is 0.201, then I use this new lambda seq(0.01,0.4,0.01) which I got the 'global' minimum is 0.07!

Run the code bellow, it's very impressive!
[image: the first plot]

```
eGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = (1:10) * 0.1, 
                 lambda = seq(0.01,0.4,0.01))

Control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",repeats = 3,verboseIter =TRUE)

netFit <- train(x = as.matrix(data[ , colnames(data) %in% "y" == FALSE]), 
            y = y,
            method = "glmnet",
            tuneGrid = eGrid,
            trControl = Control)
plot(netFit)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ feng! I ran your code several times and it seems like your proposed plot changes a lot, if I run the code several times. In some runs, it chooses a minima of approximately 0.07, but much more often it chooses a minima of approximately 0.2. Try to run your code with the seed `set.seed(123)`. In this case it chooses a minima of 0.2. If you run the code again with a seed of `set.seed(555)` it chooses a minima of 0.07. How could I decide which of these minima is better? My idea is to take the median of the minima of several runs. What do you think about that idea?

Comment: One further problem with `caret` is that it calculates just `lambda.min`. I would like to use `lambda.1se`, which is the largest value of lambda such that the error is within 1 standard error of the minimum. Do you know a way how I could calculate `lambda.1se` with `caret`?

Comment: @JoachimSchork  that's weird. The code above is not set the seed, I have not reproduce it . I run it with different seed, the lambda always the same (0.18), so 0.18 is corresponding the most minima rmse.

Comment: There is randomness introduced in the `train` function. If you run it several times there is a change in the output. Most of the time the best lambda is 0.18, but sometimes it changes to other values. I just ran it 20 times with seeds 1:20 and received 8 different lambdas. Try it for example with a seed of 5, the resultant best lambda would be 0.06.

Comment: I got the 0.06 before. It's local minimum,  you can compare the rmse value between 0.06 and 0.18 using glmnet with all the training data. From the above plot, you just need be find which is the global minimum.

Comment: Another way to removing the randomness, is try to using two lambada sequences which generate around the two local minimum.  Then you will get the unchanged and best results

Comment: OK I will try that. Thank you very much for your help, the discussion helped a lot to get a better understanding about the process of cross validation!